# Swift creation of separate timers

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, nstimer

I am trying to make a countdown timer that connects to a button, and am currently using the

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

However, I want it so if I press the same button a new timer starts with the similar settings, so in the console there are 2, 3, etc. countdown timers going at the same time.
How do I make it so whenever I press the button a new timer generates with same settings as the previous but the old one is still active and ticking down?

Comment: Do you want for each button press a new run loop gets generated? if yes, then this should be the default behavior for you code...

Answer (score 4):

To keep track of the various timers, you want to create an array of timers (`[Timer]`) and create a `TimerState` to pass into each timer as the `userInfo` object.  Then when `updateTimer()` is called, you can access the `state` for that timer as `timer.userInfo` and use it.  When a timer reaches `0`, call `invalidate()` and remove it from the list of timers.

Uses the `timers` array to stop all of the active timers if the user presses the <kbd>Stop All Timers</kbd> button.

```
import UIKit

class TimerState {
    let number: Int
    var count: Int

    init(number: Int, count: Int) {
        self.number = number
        self.count = count
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var timerNumber = 1
    var startingCount = 10

    // Array to hold active timers so that all can be stopped
    var timers = [Timer]()

    @IBAction func startTimer(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let state = TimerState(number: timerNumber, count: startingCount)

        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(updateTimer), userInfo: state, repeats: true)

        timers.append(timer)

        timerNumber += 1
    }

    @objc func updateTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
        guard let state = timer.userInfo as? TimerState else { return }
        state.count -= 1
        if state.count == 0 {
            print("Timer \(state.number) is done")
            timer.invalidate()

            // remove this timer from the list of active timers
            if let index = timers.firstIndex(of: timer) {
                timers.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            print("Timer \(state.number): \(state.count)")
        }
    }

    @IBAction func stopAllTimers(_ sender: UIButton) {
        for timer in timers {
            guard let state = timer.userInfo as? TimerState else { continue }
            print("Timer \(state.number) stopped")

            timer.invalidate()
        }
    }
}
```

---

Pressing the <kbd>Start Timer</kbd> button 3 times yields the following output in the console:

> ```
> Timer 1: 9
> Timer 1: 8
> Timer 1: 7
> Timer 2: 9
> Timer 1: 6
> Timer 2: 8
> Timer 1: 5
> Timer 2: 7
> Timer 3: 9
> Timer 1: 4
> Timer 2: 6
> Timer 3: 8
> Timer 1: 3
> Timer 2: 5
> Timer 3: 7
> Timer 1: 2
> Timer 2: 4
> Timer 3: 6
> Timer 1: 1
> Timer 2: 3
> Timer 3: 5
> Timer 1 is done
> Timer 2: 2
> Timer 3: 4
> Timer 2: 1
> Timer 3: 3
> Timer 2 is done
> Timer 3: 2
> Timer 3: 1
> Timer 3 is done
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code:

```
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I would assume that you are declaring `timer` as an instance variable in `ViewController` something like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var timer: Timer?

    @IBAction func tapped(_ sender: Any) {
        timer?.invalidate()

        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func clock() {
        print("counting...")
    }
}
```

So each tap on the button, it will schedule a new timing session even if you are using the same `Timer` instance. In this case, what you should do is to *[invalidate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415405-invalidate)* `timer` each time before assigning `Timer.scheduledTimer` to it:

> Stops the timer from ever firing again and requests its removal from
>   its run loop.

In the button action method, add `timer?.invalidate()` in the first:

```
@IBAction func tapped(_ sender: Any) {
    timer?.invalidate()

    timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `Timer()` instance for each button press (if you do indeed want multiple timers) with the same properties.

Would be worth keeping a list of all of your Timers though so you can deal with them when you no longer need them (so you don't have many tens of timers building up if someone spammed the button).

Comment: If you act on your existing `timer` instance, you'll just overwrite it (hence why you don't see the "old one").

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends on whether you need to track all of those timers or not. If not is pretty straightforward. Just create a timer each time you click on the button:

```
func buttonDidClick() {
    Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}
```

if you need to keep track of those timers use an Array:

```
func buttonDidClick() {
        myArray.append(Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.clock), userInfo: nil, repeats: true))
    }
```

This way you can even cancel all the timers or do anything you need.

Comment: lets say I appended both timers to the array, how then would I print out data from those two timers ticking simultaneously?

Comment: You might loop through the array, stop all the timers with timer.invalidate() and instantiate them again with Timer.scheduledTimer (you should do this each time the user click on the button).